# Find data of a whole month in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query where I provide to-date & from date.

```
SELECT * 
FROM sales 
WHERE date between to-date AND from-date;
```

Now I want to execute this query with following parameters

```
to-date = Oct-2015

some-other-date = Oct-2015
```

That is I want records of the whole month.

How would I do that in a query where I have `to` and `from` `dates` provided it will work for both scenarios where months can be same and different as well.

**Update:**

`dataType` for `column` `date` is `date`

Comment: what are the data types of `to-date` and `from-date` ? What is the format of input values ?

Comment: date formats are as mentioned in parameters.

Comment: I think you need to provide more clarification about your problem... I am not quite sure what are you asking!?

Comment: To make it simpler, I have this interface where user can view data between a range of months, for instance either he/she can select Jan-2014 - Feb-2014 or Feb-2014 - April-2015. What if he/she want to view data something like Jan-2015, but as I have two parameters so I want to handle such condition.

Comment: I think (?) you would need to pass the two dates in as parameters, evaluate if they are the same month (and year), and if they are then you need to find the last day of the `@from-date` parameter. If they aren't the same date (month and year), then you haven't said what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the first day of the month containing any given timestamp with an expression like this. For example by using the timestamp `NOW()`, this finds the first day of the present month.

```
(DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(DATE(NOW()))
```

That's handy, because then you can use an expression like

```
(DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(DATE(NOW())) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

to find the beginning of the previous month if you like. All sorts of date arithmetic become available.

Therefore, you can use an expression like the following to find all records with `item_date` in the month before the present month.

```
WHERE item_date>=(DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(DATE(NOW()))- INTERVAL 1 MONTH
  AND item_date < (DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(DATE(NOW()))
```

Notice that we cast the end of a range of time as an *inequality* (`<`) to the moment just after then end of the range of time.

You may find this writeup useful.  http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/

It's often useful to create a stored function called `TRUNC_MONTH()` to perform the conversion of the arbitrary timestamp to the first day of the month. It makes your SQL statements easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from sales 
where from-date >= 1-Oct-2015 
and to-date <= 1-Nov-2015
```

**Update**

```
 select * from sales 
where date >= from-date 
and date <= to-date
```

Here is [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9be7/1)

You Can get month from your both `to` and `from` dates and find records of that month

```
SELECT * FROM sales
WHERE MONTH('2002-01-03') AND MONTH('2002-01-3')
```

[SqlFiddle of Using Month Function](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9be7/3)

Comment: I don't have date available otherwise it would be as simple as you suggested.

Comment: @Sajjad : I have updated my answer try it may be it will helpful to you

Comment: I specifically mentioned that I have parameters having format
MM-yyyy
so this solution won't work.